# Not able to access statefulset via headless service fqdn

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

```
kc get svc springboot-abc -n runtime
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
springboot-abc   ClusterIP   None         <none>        80/TCP    10m
```

(above is the headless service)

```
kc get pod -n runtime | grep springboot-abc
springboot-abc-0                                   2/2     Running   0          11m
springboot-abc-1                                   2/2     Running   0          11m
springboot-abc-2                                   2/2     Running   0          10m
```

(above is the statefulset pod)

```
root@dnsutils:/# nslookup springboot-abc.runtime
Server:         172.16.128.10
Address:        172.16.128.10#53

Name:   springboot-abc.runtime.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.16.17.79
Name:   springboot-abc.runtime.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.16.18.35
Name:   springboot-abc.runtime.svc.cluster.local
Address: 172.16.3.98
```

(after I ran into a dnsutil pod , you can see the nslookup command can get the backend pod list  ip)

**but I failed to hit the headless service by dns name like below, it will show the connection refused, this is my question, how to resolve this issue?.**

```
(app-root) bash-4.2$ curl springboot-abc.runtime/ping
curl: (7) Failed connect to springboot-abc.runtime:80; Connection refused
```

but you can see that I can hit the pod directly by dns name, my pod is on 8080 port and headless service is on 80 port.

```
(app-root) bash-4.2$ curl springboot-abc-0.springboot-abc.runtime:8080/ping
hello world(app-root) bash-4.2$
```

**notes: I was deploying use helm chart in azure aks, and do not have very clear service.yaml. below is the service yaml by kubectl edit.**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: springboot
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2023-09-08T01:09:03Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: springboot
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: abc
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v2023.17.0303
    helm.sh/chart: ABC-TD
    module: TPD
  name: springboot-abc
  namespace: runtime
  resourceVersion: "108909758"
  uid: 542813af-cd0c-42fc-bb33-10d9ef612ca6
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  clusterIPs:
  - None
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: springboot
    app.kubernetes.io/name: abc
    module: TPD
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```